Conda environments with no name in VS Code
I am using miniconda on a macOS.  When I try to conda environments from the terminal in VS Code, for some envs I have to specify a path vice just a name.  If I list the environments I get a list like below:
(base) MAC-M1-16-ccc:~ xxxxxxxx$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/git/neuralnets/.conda
base                  *  /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3
634d00_analysis          /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/634d00_analysis
SOS                      /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/SOS
engagementRerun          /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/engagementRerun
processCreate            /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/processCreate
pythonProject            /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/pythonProject
text_column_explore      /Users/xxxxxxxx/miniconda3/envs/text_column_explore
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/opt/miniconda3
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/Primer
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/SOS
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/clean_env
                         /Users/xxxxxxxx/opt/miniconda3/envs/compress

I created all the environments from conda create -n xxx python=xxx so why are some just paths with no names?  Note that the nameless envs also have a different path.  Is there a way to force a name on to the envs with just a path?

This answer might help answer the question: conda-environment-has-no-name

@topsail tnx!  That addresses how to correct fix it.  I'm still curious about why it even happens

.../opt/ - installed with Homebrew? If so, that's probably [at least part of] why it happened.

@l3l_aze I used miniconda for all the creations but some are older than others.  Would conda create have changed over the past say, 1.5 years?

IDK as I'm not a regular Python user, sorry. Just have experience with Homebrew causing random issues for the tools it installs.

I discovered this is related to the shell used when creating the environment.  In VS Code a drop down allows you to choose the terminal you wish to open.  I use three bash, zsh, tmux.  To use conda in a shell you have to do conda init and that makes an entry in the config or profile file for the shell in particular the paths.
In .bash_profile I had:
__conda_setup="$('/Users/xxxxx/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

While in .zshrc I had:
__conda_setup="$('/Users/xxxxx/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

So I have apparently set up the envs while in different shells. While I didn't choose any paths, just ran conda init, it looks like the shells handle paths differently.
Note: the list above was from when I was in the bash shell.  When I get the list in a zsh shell the effect reverses, all the ...\opt\... envs have names and the others don't.
In the end I deleted both miniconda3 directories and reinstalled conda.  This time paid attention to the paths and will rebuild envs on an as required basis.

It looks to me like you installed miniconda twice and it just happened that one was added to bash_profile and one to zshrc. Its not really that shells somehow handle paths differently

"In the end I deleted both miniconda3 directories and reinstalled conda. This time paid attention to the paths and will rebuild envs on an as required basis." seems to be the best fix since you got rid of the two-conda confusion that way
